# Adding Observer in UICollectionViewCell. Getting exception KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer

I am adding an observer in `UICollectionViewCell` that has AVPlayer for getting the duration of the played item.

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(player.currentItem.duration), options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
```

Removing the observer in deinit method.

```
removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(player.currentItem.duration), context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
```

Getting the exception randomly saying

> KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED

Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: In which method you are adding the observer ?

Comment: I have a custom method to configurePlayer(), once player instance is ready after that I add the observer.

Comment: From which method you are calling this configurePlayer ? viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or from IBAction method ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you could add your observers make sure you removed the added observers.

Likewise, make two functions for adding and removing the observers like

To add observers

```
func addObserver() { 
   addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(player.currentItem.duration), options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)

}
```

To remove observers

```
func removeObservers() {
     removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(player.currentItem.duration), context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)

}
```

Make sure to call removeObserver() before you make calls to addObserver()

Happy coding!